# Flutter upgrade command not working getting error 'You are not currently on a release branch'

Tags: flutter, flutter-upgrade

**Flutter upgrade** command not working getting error **'You are not currently on a release branch. Use git to check out an official branch ('stable', 'beta', 'dev', or 'master')'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Go to your flutter stored path from terminal**

```
cd path
```

**2. Hit command**

```
git checkout stable
```

**3. Hit command**

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: `flutter channel stable` worked for me (instead of `git checkout stable`)